# Magento 2 : Replace final_price.phtml on certain categories

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.2.4

I'm using 2.2.4 and need to be able to load a different final_price.phtml dependant on which category we are in (and I need to do it as a layout update in admin for the category as I need someone non techy to be able to copy the code into a new category).

I have created the new `final_price.phtml` in `/app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/` and renamed it `final_price_sl.phtml`

Is there a way to add code to the layout update so on specific categories it loads `final_price_sl.phtml` instead of `final_price.phtml`?

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out, final working code is

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="priceTable" template="Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price_sl.phtml" after="product.info.price" /></referenceContainer>
```

Comment: how did you assign which categories to use the new template? thanks

Comment: Above code is simply pasted into the 'Layout Update XML' box in the design section of each category we want it in.

Comment: i see, thanks a lot.